# How to configure Mattermost?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to use Mattermost as an alternative on Microsoft teams on Linux. How can I configure it as it says that I have to enter my server details, URL and Display name. Do I have to build my own server? The proble with Teams is that I can't hear customer's voice so I try to replace Teams with Mattermost.

Comment: Are you talking about using Mattermost instead of Teams to partake in meetings? If not, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739953/edit) the question to clarify your exact need. If yes, this might be of help: https://mattermost.com/marketplace/microsoft-teams-meetings/

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about that. I don't hear the voice during Teams meeting so I am trying to use Mattermost for online meeting software.

Comment: You should add the new info and clarifications directly to the question by editing it. That way it stays up to date and relevant info stays available. The link I provided which describes how to use Mattermost to partake in Teams meetings was not helpful either?

Comment: Well, one can read the up to date versions by the timestamps. I don't need to connect the Teams meetings but I would be able to replace Teams by Mattermost.

Comment: Now you really have to clarify your need. You're in discussion with a customer, but you're not in a Teams meeting???? Please note that these aren't discussion forums, but Q&A sites. You _can_ force others to waddle through comments to keep tabs of your situation and what you're doing instead of making it clear in your question, but what exactly is the benefit of this approach?